# How to grep to get multiple lines with a specific format, but if one of the lines has a specific word, do not include the lines as a result

Tags: grep

I have a large directory of files, which I need to look through for specific lines, because they need to be updated.

The format I am looking for always starts with <topicref, and then after that, it must have
href="../, but will have some text after it. For example: href="../example.md". After that, it might have scope="peer", some other lines, and will end off with either > or />.

So far, I've come up with a regex that address finding the lines I want:

```
pcregrep -HnM '<topicref(.*) href="..\/(.*).dita(.*)[^>]*'
```

However, I'm having trouble filtering out the results that have scope="peer". I tried doing

```
pcregrep -HnM '<topicref(.*) href="..\/(.*).dita(.*)[^>]*' directory | pcregrep - Mv 'scope="peer" > file
```

But the results from this would strictly show all the lines that don't have 'scope="peer"' in it from the overall result from the previous pcregrep, so there would be random results that shouldn't be included, and also I am unable to track which files these results are from.

Is it possible to see all the `<topicref href="../... >` mentions without `scope="peer"`?

Three examples of lines with scope="peer":

```
<topicref href="../cat.md" scope="peer"
something />

<topicref href="../cat.md"
something scope="peer"
something />

<topicref href="../cat.md"
scope="peer"
something></topicref><map>
```

Comment: I think you want a *"negative lookbehind"*... https://caspar.bgsu.edu/~courses/Stats/Labs/Handouts/grepadvanced.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
pcregrep -HnM '<topicref(?![^>]*\sscope="peer")(?:\s[^>]+)?\shref="\.\./([^"]*)\.dita[^>]*>' file
```

*Details*

- `<topicref` - a literal string
- `(?![^>]*\sscope="peer")` - no whitespace + `scope="peer"` allowed after any zero or more chars other than `>` immediately to the right of the current position
- `(?:\s[^>]+)?` - an optional whitespace, one or more chars other than `>`
- `\shref="\.\./` - whitespace, `href="../` string
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\.dita` - `.dita` string (replace with `\.md` if you need to match `.md`)
- `[^>]*>` - zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`.